# How to read excel file with Java without external jars

Tags: java, excel

I'm trying to read excel file and pass all the data to DB. I found a few code examples but all of them required external jars. How can I read excel files using only the standard library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IF you don't want to use a library then you will have to download the [Excel file format specs from MS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313118%28office.12%29.aspx) and write an Excel parser yourself (which is extremely complicated and takes > 10 years for one developer). For the OpenXML format spec see [here](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=51463) and [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm).

Thus I really recommend using a library for that...

Try [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) - a free Java library for dealing with MS Office documents..

Comment: I don't want to add library to my project.

Comment: @OferTaviv If you don't want to add a library then you will have to download the Excel file format specs from MS and write an Excel parser yourself (which is extremely complicated and takes > 10 years for one developer).

Comment: Sorry, but that's just a stupid idea. To read Excel file format you will have to write lots of complex code. If you really don't want to use an external library, you should definitely consider using a different format like CSV. Trying to read XLS without using any existing library is like starting to build a car by purchasing a rubber plantation to be able to produce your own tyres...

Answer (score 0):

You can save as the excel file *.cvs and sperated ";". Then, you can read file line by line and get the columns which is getting from each token.

Comment: I know, but the conversion from excel to csv doesn't support utf-8

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft excel uses a binary way to save its data, so manually reading excel files might be a hassle. If you could convert the excel (xls) to a comma seperated values (csv) file, then you can just read the file and split your input on the comma's.

Comment: I know, but the conversion from excel to csv doesn't support utf-8

Answer (score -1):

This is a difficult problem. First off, it is not as simple as "adding a third party library". There are no existing EXCEL reading libraries that do not cost money and the one that I know that does work is very expensive AND has bugs in it.

One strategy is to create an Excel add in that reads the data and transfers it to your application by OLE or the clipboard or by a TCP/IP port or saves it to a temporary file. If you look in the source code for OPeNDAP.org's ODC project you can find an Excel add in and TCP capability to do this.

You can try referring to the reader in OpenOffice which is open source code, however, in my opinion that code is not easily refactorable into a private project for various reasons.

Microsoft has components and tools to open Excel files and expose them via COM objects.

You can also learn the BIFF format and write your own parser. You probably would want to write a parser for BIFF5, but be forewarned, this is a BIG project, even if you only parse a limited number of data types.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the first paragraph, but there are at least 2 open source examples  of libraries mentioned on this site that can read/write Excel files that are claimed to work well.