# Reading data from Excel using Java

Tags: java, excel

I have 2 columns in an excel sheet, A and B, and I need to divide column A (randomly) into 2 and calculate the average of the first and second halves of column B separately. Then I need to divide column A again but each time moving with one cell downwards and calculate the averages etc. Can this be done using Java only? Since I am finding you have to use software like Apache and I have never used them.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108394/how-to-read-excel-file-with-java-without-external-jars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach would be to save the Excel file as a comma-separated values (.CSV) file.

Since you have never used a framework before, I will show you how to use the [OpenCSV framework](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net).

First you need to add this framework to your Build Path. Drag the downloaded .jar files to your workspace in Eclipse. Open the project's properties, Select Java Build Path, Select Libraries tab, and then Add a Library from Workspace and select that jar file.

To use it, your class will look something like this,

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;

public class CSV {

    private List<String[]> fileContent;

    public CSV(String filePath) {
        try {
            readCSV(filePath);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.print("There was an error reading this CSV file. Error follows:");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void readCSV(String csvPath) throws IOException {
        // Store coupon objects in array list
        CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvPath));

        // Store each row into a String list
        List<String[]> csvData = csvReader.readAll();

        csvReader.close();
        fileContent = csvData;
    }

    public void printFileContent() {
        System.out.println("");
        for (String[] row : fileContent.subList(1, fileContent.size())) {

            for (String s: row) {

                 System.out.print(s + " ");

             }

            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Inside the main method, you can use a simple

```
CSV csvFile = new CSV("csv/Path/Here.csv");
// Verify Results
csvFile.printFileContent();
```

*As always, please use my code as a reference. It is always better to learn how to write code yourself, especially when this question pertains to a homework assignment.*

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can save the Excel data as a text file and use classes like java.io.File, java.util.Scanner to read the text file.

Comment: Can I program it to move one column down from Java as well?

Comment: what do you mean by "move one column down"?  You can store the values of columns A and B in a 2-dimensional array by the way.